# What is the correct PayPal code for my product?

Tags: html, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a PayPal shop I am developing for a client and I have a problem with the code because I get an error when attempting to add a product to the cart.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here's an example: http://www.karenrothwell.com/?product=mokume-gane-cufflinks.

I have been led to believe my secure merchant id can be used in place of the "business" input with the paypal account's email address.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to go to either your shops settings, account settings, and or product settings on PayPal so you may obtain the correct code that corresponds with the correct product.

http://www.paypal.com/

Comment: i agree it may be an account issue. however I am dynamically generating the markup for the buttons and not via the paypal button code generator as this would be unwise.